# Does the value of window.scrolltop() change when toolbar/addressbar on mobile devices collapses

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am doing some calculations with `$(window).scrollTop();`, `element.innerHeight();`, `$(window).height();`, `element.offset().top;`. And i've noticed that the result is different on mobile devices due to the toolbar from chrome and safari. My question is do any of those values change when the toolbar collapses and what can i do against it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the past, and solved it by setting the `position` as `fixed` for the `body`. Maybe that will help you as well.

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388367/mobile-safari-window-height-url-bar-discrepancy), also there is a `jQuery.documentSize` solution on [github](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize) which detects the real width and height of the document.

Comment: Didn't really work for me.

Comment: @Kiri Try that way:
`body { min-height: 100vh; min-height: -webkit-fill-available; } html { height: -webkit-fill-available; }`

Comment: Also please check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655549/13199446) that might be a solution